# How set FilterExtensions for Swing JDialog?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

How filter the files by extensions (in the screen), like this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/SetFilterExtensionsforFileDialog.htm)

thanks,
celso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FileNameExtensionFilter` to filter certain file extension in `JFileChooser`. [The API doc for it](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileNameExtensionFilter.html) gives a short example:

```
FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPEG file", "jpg", "jpeg");
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
```